# plotly.js : Including HTML Table in the graph tooltip

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly

I have a scenario in my application while using Plotly.js where I’d like to include HTML in the tooltip, I am planning to include a HTML table in the tooltip, to look something similar to this.
[image]

Any leads on how to do this please? Thanks

Comment: Please seek [ask]. You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: @isherwood, sorry for that. I have included an image of how it would look like. Please let me know if this provides enough info. Thanks